# Manjaro Volume Doesn't Affect Actual Volume

Tags: audio, manjaro

I just freshly installed Manjaro `4.9.50-1-MANJARO` with Gnome, and I'm having problems with the volume control, namely, when I play audio e.g. on Firefox and use the volume controls either on my keyboard, or in the system bar slider, the audio is unaffected and stays very loud.

I can only control it via getting into the sound settings, selecting the applications tab and controlling the particular application's volume slider.

How can I make the system volume control all applications' volume? All I've found googling so far was the exact oposite question - unlinking the system volume from application volume, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The same problem was present even before installation, i.e. when trying to set the volume on the live usb. I have an ASUS Zenbook 3 Deluxe

Comment: Try `Antergos`, it is also arch based